# Angular.js routing doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm teaching myself some AngularJS and have made some progress.
The routing on the following project doesn't seem to work but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I use WebStorm.

I did an exercise (the adding names part) and now I'm trying to show what's within the views on the index page but this doesn't seem to work..
Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
    <h1>Lijst met namen</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="voornaam..." ng-model="ctrl.voornaam">
    <input type="text" placeholder="achternaam..." ng-model="ctrl.name">
    <input type="button" value="Persoon toevoegen" ng-click="ctrl.addNaam()">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in ctrl.personen">
            {{person.name}} {{person.voornaam}}
        </li>
    </ul>



</div>
<div role="navigation">
    <nav>
        <a href="#/home">Home</a>
        <a href="#/about">About us</a>
        <a href="#/contact">Contact us</a>
    </nav>
</div>
<div ng-view></div>




<script src="controller.js"></script>
<script src="aboutController.js"></script>
<script src="contactController.js"></script>
<script src="homeController.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

App.js:

```
angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']).config(moduleConfig);

//Inject dependencies
moduleConfig.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

//routes configureren
function moduleConfig($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'homeController',
            controllerAs: 'homeCtrl'
        })
            .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'homeController',
                controllerAs: 'homeCtrl'
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
            controller: 'aboutController',
            controllerAs: 'aboutCtrl'
        })
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
            controller: 'contactController',
            controllerAs: 'contactCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
} })();
```

Controller.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myController', myController);
function myController(){
     var vm = this;

     vm.personen = [
         {name: 'Schrooten', voornaam: 'Mathias'}
     ];

     vm.addNaam = function(){
          var newName = {
              voornaam: this.voornaam,
              name: this.name
          };
          this.personen.push(newName);
          window.alert('Persoon toegevoegd!')
     }
 }
```

aboutController:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('aboutController', aboutController);
function aboutController(){
  this.msg = 'Hello';
}
```

2 other controllers look almost the same (contactController.js and homeController.js)

views: 
about.html:

```
<div>
    <p>About us: ....</p>

    <input type="text">
</div>
```

Same for 2 other views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `angular.module('myApp')` is a redundant code in your codebase. creating angular modules everywhere is the incorrect thing here. Create it once, store it in a variable, lets say 'app' and use it everywhere else.

Like as follows:

in app.js :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

in route.js :

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'login.html'
        })
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl : 'main.html',
            controller: 'myController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

In Controller.js :

```
app.controller('myController', myController);
function myController(){
     var vm = this;

     vm.personen = [
         {name: 'Schrooten', voornaam: 'Mathias'}
     ];

     vm.addNaam = function(){
          var newName = {
              voornaam: this.voornaam,
              name: this.name
          };
          this.personen.push(newName);
          window.alert('Persoon toegevoegd!')
     }
 }
```

You can refer to one of my github repositories to understand a basic angular framework that uses template routing for a single page application [here](https://github.com/theScratchLad/lax-ui).

Comment: Welcome Mathias Schrooten :)

Comment: the problem @SatyajitPatnaik  however isn't redundancy, is initializing the module twice

Comment: @koox00 Yeah right, By saying redundancy, I was trying to say that only, I guess I used the wrong word to define the case. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

this line `angular.module('myApp', [])` initializes a module.
So basically you have to initialize once.
then you can use it like this `angular.module('myApp')`

so this in you code:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myController', myController);
```

has to become like the line below because you already have `myApp` module defined:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', myController);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do:

```
angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']).config(['$routeprovider', moduleConfig]);
```

And then you should be able to get rid of the .$inject you call.

Comment: what is actually going wrong? It just doesn't load the view that you want?

Comment: @MathiasSchrooten also can you go to the console and see if any errors are being logged?

Comment: It gives me this error: ' Uncaught ReferenceError: aboutController is not defined'

Comment: And it doesn't load the views when I click the links 'Home', 'About us' or 'Contact' and that's what I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

From your code as first I see this line looks to be wrong, when you register your 'myController' controller. There you are using `angular.module('myApp', [])` hovewer in App.js there is the 'myApp' module created. In 'Cotnroller.js' use `angular.module('myApp').controller(...)` without brackets. Currenlty in Controller.js you overwrite the 'myApp' module.